# iOS, autolayout to add a margin / spacer for iPhone 5 but not iPhone 4?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm a bit rusty with autolayout, following my refresh / research I can't figure out how to achieve what I need. I'm only supporting landscape. And I'm just working on my compact layout here.

I have just the right amount of space on iPhone 4. However I need to add some spacing panels or left and right margins just for iPhone 5.

He's a quick mockup. I need to add spacing in sections A. Sections B are the same ascpect

iPhone 5

```
######################
# A BBBBB    BBBBB A #
# A BBBBB    BBBBB A #
# A BBBBB    BBBBB A #
# A BBBBB    BBBBB A #
######################
```

iPhone 4

```
##################
# BBBBB    BBBBB #
# BBBBB    BBBBB #
# BBBBB    BBBBB #
# BBBBB    BBBBB #
##################
```

EDIT
Sums from answer below...
[image]

Comment: If you want to have a custom layout for different size screens, you need to have multiple storboards.

Comment: You could give it a fixed width equal to the iPhone 4 screen width and then center it in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when I need a different size spacing for different sizes of screen I create helper views (lets call them spacers)

Create a view and pin it to the edge to the left (and also top and bottom, but it doesn't really matter) and set its Width to be equal to the superview width (the top superview).

Now edit its width constraint to fit your purpose (for example if you want `15` points on `iPhone 5` but `0` on `iPhone 4` you could use `0.166` in ratio and `-80` in the constant field.

Pin your view to this `spacer` and have fun :) ( you could do it for both edges of the screen)

For everyone wondering how I got the numbers:
`ax + b = y`, in our case we have to formulas we need to solve:
480 = iPhone 4 screen height (or width in landscape mode)
568 = iPhone 5 screen height (or width in landscape mode)

```
 a * 480 + b = 0 ----- this is the iPhone 4 formula
 a * 568 + b = 15 ----- this is the iPhone 5 formula
 480a = -b
 568a - 480a = 15
 a = 15 / 88
 0.17 * 480 + b = 0
 b = -81.6
```

Adding an image to make this clear : [image: Spacer View]

Comment: Thanks @EliBraginskiy how does 15 points derive from 0.166 / -80 ? This is opposite to what I'm looking for, I want more on iPhone 4.

Comment: @Jules You said you want more spacing for the iPhone 5 didn't you?

Comment: Oh sorry yes, getting confused. That seems fine, once I worked out the values. Can I ask how you worked it out ? I've added my workings to my question, 2 secs..

Comment: @Jules When I work I constructed a formula (numbers) to do this for me, but its basically Math. Im updating the answer to reflect how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `B`'s to be center aligned, equal width with some spacing between them. And then when there is some extra space(in case of iPhone 5) it will be around the `B` and you'll achieve your goal.

I'll write you detailed explanation a little later, but the idea will work.